# how to filter an Observable array?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire

[image]

My method returns an Observable array from Firebase. I have decided to filter the data in the client rather than in the server. My problem is that I want to get only the data if the attribute "attending = true". Any help or other approach is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

The method below get the data from the firebase real-time database

```
userEvents: Observable<any[]>;

getUserEvents(uid: string) {
this.userEvents = this.db.list(this.basePatheventsSaved, ref=> 
 ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid)).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
  return actions.map((a) => {
    const data = a.payload.val();
    const $key = a.payload.key;
    return { $key, ...data };
  });
});
return this.userEvents;
}
```

The code below is used to fecth the data to be used in the templaTe:

```
 userEvents: Observable<any[]>;
 constructor(public auth: AuthService, private upSvc: FilesServiceService) { 
this.userEvents = this.upSvc.getUserEvents(this.auth.currentUserId);
 }
```

Comment: uh... `filter` operator doesn't work for you?

Comment: I tried but i get this error "[ts] Property 'attending' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
any"

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to use the `map` and the `filter` operators for this, combined with `Array.prototype.filter`. If I've understood your data correctly it should be something like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

userEvents: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(public auth: AuthService, private upSvc: FilesServiceService) { 
  this.userEvents = this.upSvc.getUserEvents(this.auth.currentUserId)
    .map(items => items.filter(item => item.attending))
    .filter(items => items && items.length > 0);
}
```

First we filter the array down to only items where `attending` is true.
Then we filter out any empty or null arrays.

### Updated for RXJS 6:

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

userEvents: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(public auth: AuthService, private upSvc: FilesServiceService) { 
  this.userEvents = this.upSvc.getUserEvents(this.auth.currentUserId)
    .pipe(
      map(items => items.filter(item => item.attending)),
      filter(items => items && items.length > 0)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use the rxjs filter method for this, but rather the filter method on the array object that you receive from the observable.

So if you have an `Observable<any[]>` you would filter it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

this.userEvents.map( arr =>
           arr.filter( r => r.attending === true )
     )
     .subscribe( results => console.log('Filtered results:', results))
```

From rxjs 5.5 you should use `.pipe` instead of `.map` directly on the Observable:

```
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 this.userEvents.pipe( 
         map(arr =>
           arr.filter( r => r.attending === true )
         )
     )
     .subscribe( results => console.log('Filtered results:', results))
```

Comment: When applying the first option at runtime I get the error map is undefined, and the in the second one "pipe" has not exported member.  The problem is solved though. Thank you  very much for your help

Comment: Sorry should have imported map on both options and not import pipe on the second. Corrected now.

Comment: Consider changing the following sentence: "You cannot use the rxjs filter method for this" IMO
You should also use the rxjs filter method to filter out any empty or null arrays.